# Debugging Maven project terminates JFrame creation

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, maven

I have a maven project with 4 dependencies. The project begins with creating a JFrame, initializing it, and displaying it.

When attempting to debug the program, the debugger terminates at

```
JFrame test = new JFrame("test");
```

while trying to create the JFrame.

This does not happen when I compile and run the jar outside of Eclipse.

If I remove all the dependencies from the pom, the JFrame will be created and displayed as normal.

What could be causing Eclipse to terminate the debugger on JFrame creation?

I've tried reinstalling Java, recreating the project, recreating the project in a new workspace, and using the same pom settings in a test project, all of which resulted in the same behavior of terminating at JFrame creation.

Edit: Here's the problem code and pom.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JFrame test = new JFrame("test");
            test.add(new JLabel("test"));
            test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            test.pack();

            test.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.so.test.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Example-Project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pro.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pro.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>interactive</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.miglayout</groupId>
            <artifactId>miglayout-swing</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>beam-releases</id>
            <url>https://maven.beam.pro/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>beam-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://maven.beam.pro/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I've narrowed it down to deleting the beam and spark dependencies will allow the JFrame to create, but I haven't determined why. I made sure I'm using versions that can be found.

Comment: Without having any details about what you're importing, how you're initialising your frame, or what error you're getting, we can't possibly have any idea.  Sorry.

Comment: The initialization is literally what's in the question. I'm not getting any errors even in a try-catch (throwable).

Comment: Could you write a [mcve] of both your code and the POM file? It'll make it easier to isolate issues.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I added the requested code and POM. If you're able to run it on your end then it's likely just an issue with my machine.

Comment: I'm just trying to get your question good enough that it's easy to answer. I have no more ideas than you for this :P

Comment: Appreciate it nonetheless :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that something about the latest NVIDIA 1070 graphics driver broke this. I uninstalled driver #378.49 and reinstalled #376.33 and it now works.